# rpm package 'libatomic1' is not installed

Tags: sles

I am in middle of installation of HANA Express addition on SUSE Linux server (sles-12-sp3) but when I tried to install the HANA I am getting an issue i.e "rpm package 'libatomic1' is not installed".
I am not aware how to install this required package and from where I can download it.
Please guide me if someone faced this issue.

Comment: please try to install  ```zypper install libgcc_s1 libstdc++6 libatomic1```

Comment: More details you can find [here](https://github.com/Azure/sap-hana/issues/218)

Answer (score 0):

```
zypper install libgcc_s1 libstdc++6 libatomic1
```